# PHPMailer Sending just One File

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am trying to send email with multiple attachments using PHPMailer class. Multiple files are uploading successfully in directory but it's sending just one file in Email. And how to format my email body using bootstrap? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated. I am using PHPMailer 6.0.5

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
<?php 

    $msg = '';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    include_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    // include_once 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $inputZip = $_POST['inputZip'];
        $selectService = $_POST['selectService'];
        $lawnMovingService = $_POST['lawnMovingService'];
        $leafRemovalService = $_POST['leafRemovalService'];
        $snowPlowingService = $_POST['snowPlowingService'];
        $handymanService = $_POST['handymanService'];
        $inputName = $_POST['inputName'];
        $inputEmail = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $inputPhone = $_POST['inputPhone'];
        $inputMessage = $_POST['inputMessage'];

        if (isset($_FILES['images']['name']) && $_FILES['images']['name'] != '') {
            $destination = "attachment/";
            foreach ($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = $destination . basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
            }
        } else {
            $name = '';
        }

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        //For SMTP 
        //$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //$mail->isSMTP(); // This line may cause problem
        //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
        //$mail->Password = "examplePassword";
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //OR TLS
        //$mail->Port = 465; //TLS : 587

        $mail->addAddress('milan.uptech@gmail.com');
        $mail->setFrom($inputEmail);
        $mail->Subject = 'Service Booking from Website';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $inputMessage;
        $mail->addAttachment($name);

        if ($mail->send()) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: contact.php');
        }

        // if(sendemail('milan.uptech@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $file)) {
        //      $msg = 'Email Sent!';
        //      sendemail($inputEmail, 'milan.uptech@gmail.com', $inputName, 'We have received your email');
        //  }
    }
```

Comment: you need to call addAttachment() for every file you want to attach, so in the loop

Comment: @smith How can I loop addAttachment() 
Do you have any good example?

Comment: I'll add an answer in a moment,

Comment: Basically, just move your foreach loop down to where you are doing `addAttachment` and move the `addAttachment` call inside it.

Comment: @smith I wish I can mark your answer as perfect solution. ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic you mean Like This: https://pastebin.com/RVg2Nvdx

Comment: You could always use the [send multiple file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer rather than going to all this effort of writing a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the class creation up to be before the file file processing loop, and moved the attachment code in to the loop

```
<?php 

    $msg = '';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    include_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    // include_once 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $inputZip = $_POST['inputZip'];
        $selectService = $_POST['selectService'];
        $lawnMovingService = $_POST['lawnMovingService'];
        $leafRemovalService = $_POST['leafRemovalService'];
        $snowPlowingService = $_POST['snowPlowingService'];
        $handymanService = $_POST['handymanService'];
        $inputName = $_POST['inputName'];
        $inputEmail = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $inputPhone = $_POST['inputPhone'];
        $inputMessage = $_POST['inputMessage'];

        $mail = new PHPMailer; //moved here

        if (isset($_FILES['images']['name']) && $_FILES['images']['name'] != '') {
            $destination = "attachment/";
            foreach ($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = $destination . basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
                $mail->addAttachment($name); //attache here
            }
        } else {
            $name = '';
        }



        //For SMTP 
        //$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //$mail->isSMTP(); // This line may cause problem
        //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
        //$mail->Password = "examplePassword";
        //$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; //OR TLS
        //$mail->Port = 465; //TLS : 587

        $mail->addAddress('milan.uptech@gmail.com');
        $mail->setFrom($inputEmail);
        $mail->Subject = 'Service Booking from Website';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $inputMessage;


        if ($mail->send()) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: contact.php');
        }

        // if(sendemail('milan.uptech@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $file)) {
        //      $msg = 'Email Sent!';
        //      sendemail($inputEmail, 'milan.uptech@gmail.com', $inputName, 'We have received your email');
        //  }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Works Perfectly. Another question is how can I format email body using bootstrap or plain css? and is it possible to let the sender know "we have received your message" with customized message?

Comment: @MilanUptech $inputMessage is your body, you can add any html you like  but email html and web-page html are not the same, you dont want to do anything to fancy if you want all email clients to support it. currently on success you redirect to 'index.php' you could change that

Comment: This is unsafe - you're not checking the return value of `move_uploaded_file`, and just assuming it worked. It's also unsafe to use filenames provided by the user. Take a look at how [the PHPMailer example that does the same thing](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) avoids both these issues.

Comment: @smith Oh. Thanks. I am trying to redirect it to paypal payment page with amount value. So I was just trying putting index.php redirection.